# Trying to list files on excel spreadsheet VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, openfiledialog

I am trying to navigate to a folder using the Openfile Dialog command, then select some files. With these selected files, I am trying to write the name of those files onto a excel spreadsheet. I can navigate to the folder, but I can't get the files to write onto the spreadsheet.

I have the following code:

```
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim openFile1 As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()


    Dim Row As Integer
    Row = 14

    Const Column_A As Integer = 1
    Const Column_B As Integer = 2
    Const Column_C As Integer = 3
    Const Column_D As Integer = 4
    Const Column_E As Integer = 5
    Const Column_F As Integer = 6
    Const Column_U As Integer = 21

    openFile1.Title = "Open File Dialog"    'Title header for dialog box
    openFile1.InitialDirectory = "C:\" 'Initial directory for file dialog box
    openFile1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|" 'Filter all files
    openFile1.Multiselect = True 'Allows the user to select to select multiple files


    Dim Folder As IO.FileInfo()
    Dim FileName As IO.FileInfo

    If openFile1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then 'This gives the "ok" to actually open the pop-up window
        For Each FileName In Folder.SelectedItems
            strFileName = openFile1.FileName  'Stores the Filename inside the variable
            Big_Sheet.Cells(Row, Column_B) = FileName
            Row = Row + 1
            Big_Sheet.Cells(Row, Column_C).Value = strFileName 'Shows the variable FilePath
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: are you getting any error or something in any case using some tools like epplus or npoi to manipulate an excel file will be more efficient IMO

Answer (score 0):

A bit more research might be needed to write to an excel file like letting your program know that’s what your doing.

```
Dim xls As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xlsWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

xls = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
xlsWorkBook = xls.Workbooks.Open("Insert file directory here")
xlsWorkSheet = xlsWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

xlsWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = TextBox1.Text
```

Hope you can use this to give you a bit better understanding, research is key my friend.

Comment: Hi S Mac, this is not exactly what I am looking for, I am trying to get a pop-up file dialog window to open, and with that file dialog window, I want to select some files. With these selected files, I want the file name to be written onto the excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is what you're looking for? I created this code in an Excel VSTO Add-On project. In the project, I added a "Ribbon (Visual Designer)" item to the project, opened it, and dragged in a button from the Toolbox. I double-clicked the button and defined the following Click event code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ' First get the active worksheet
        Dim xls As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
        Dim xlsWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = xls.ActiveWorkbook
        Dim xlsWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = xlsWorkBook.ActiveSheet

        Dim strFileName As String
        Dim openFile1 As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

        Dim Row As Integer
        Row = 14

        'Const Column_A As Integer = 1
        Const Column_B As Integer = 2
        Const Column_C As Integer = 3
        'Const Column_D As Integer = 4
        'Const Column_E As Integer = 5
        'Const Column_F As Integer = 6
        'Const Column_U As Integer = 21

        openFile1.Title = "Open File Dialog"   'Title header for dialog box
        openFile1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"     'Initial directory for file dialog box
        openFile1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|"  'Filter all files
        openFile1.Multiselect = True           'Allows the user to select multiple files

        If openFile1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then ' Open the pop-up window
            ' The following code runs only if the OK button was pressed in the pop-up window
            For Each strFileName In openFile1.FileNames
                xlsWorkSheet.Cells(Row, Column_B) = IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) ' Show the filename only
                xlsWorkSheet.Cells(Row, Column_C).Value = strFileName                ' Shows the full path
                Row = Row + 1
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```